# Can alias be set for same language but different domains?

Tags: uri, domain-access

I have a site in Drupal 7, with [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) and [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) modules. I use [PathAuto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto). I can create custom links, and link to a node nid with different languages, but I am not able to create different links for different domains? Is there some module or way of achieving this? For example, for one and only node->nid = 5:

```
www.example.com/es/alias-1
```

would be equivalent to www.example.com/node/5

```
www.example.com/en/alias-2
```

would be equivalent to www.example.com/node/5

and I now need

```
www.example2.com/en/alias-3
```

to be equivalent to www.example2.com/node/5  (notice change of domain).

The system says that the URL already exists (alias-2 is using node->nid = 5 and language = 'en', so cannot repeat it, and, in any case, I cannot indicate a domain, anyway).